# How do I add blank rows to a repeater bound to a List<T>?

Tags: vb.net, controls, repeater

Is this possible? Using VB.NET.

Can I do it in the footer maybe? Would that be the best way? Bind the footer to a datatable and throw some blank rows in there?

Comment: Where do you want the rows (how do you know when to add one)?  can you just add empty data at the appropriate list index?

Comment: I want there to be a total of 15 rows, ie if there are 7 rows returned from the DB I want to add 8 blank rows.

Comment: Do you want the blank rows to alternate with the returned rows? Or on the end of the list of returned rows?

Answer (score 1):

I did this by dynaically adding HTML below the repeater, I subtracted by 15 - repeater.items.count then iterated through and added rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that or.... You could look through and set specific ones to have "margin-bottom: 25px;".